# Pasar datos en php con <a href> en una <img>

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy diseñando un catalogo web donde muestro productos de una base de datos en un `<container>` y un foreach en PHP. Columnas en la base de datos(ID, Nombre , Precio ,stock, Descripcion).

En la pagina principal solo se muestra la imagen principal pero al momento de querer darle click a la imagen que me lleve a otra donde tengo todas las imágenes.

[image: Html]

Este es el código del contenedor en HTML y la información traída desde PHP

[image: Código]

Quisiera saber si podría al momento de cargar la imagen añadirle un link hacia otra pagina pero pasando su información  ($producto['ID'];) para que en la otra pagina me enseñe todas las imágenes de ese producto.

Ejemplo mostrar todas las fotos de producto donde id=1.

Gracias

Comment: Por favor pon el código en texto para poder entender mejor el problema

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, como soy nuevo no supe como ponerlo, pero lo dejo en un texto        https://drive.google.com/file/d/111ZcZaH91SvJCswDuA1eP6Vqi-OCjBBF/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es crear un enlace en la imagen de cada libro para que te lleve a una página de detalle de ese libro. Esa página de detalle recibirá un parámetro con el identificador del libro.

Solo tendrías que envolver tu etiqueta de imagen dentro de una etiqueta de enlace `<a></a>`

```
  <a href="./detalleProducto.php?id=<?php echo $producto['ID']; ?>">
     <img title="<?php echo $producto['Nombre']; ?> alt="<?php echo $producto['Nombre'];" ...>
  </a>
```

Siendo `detalleProducto.php` la página donde mostrarás el resto de fotos o lo que consideres. En dicha página tendrás que recuperar de la URL el parámetro que se le ha pasado accediendo al elemento [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php) empleando como índice en el caso de mi ejemplo la cadena id.

Otra opción de mejora que te sugiero es emplear la [sintaxis abreviada del método `echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php), de forma que tengas que escribir menos y se simplifique el código.

> **echo** también posee una sintaxis abreviada, donde se puede poner el
> símbolo igual justo después de la etiqueta de apertura de PHP. Antes
> de PHP 5.4.0, este tipo de sintaxis abreviada únicamente funciona con
> la opción de configuración short_open_tag activada.

```
<a href="./detalleProducto.php?id=<?=$producto['ID'] ?>">
     <img title="<?=$producto['Nombre'] ?> alt="<?=$producto['Nombre'] ?>" ...
</a>
```

Comment: @LeonPerezFabian puedes responder tu mismo a la pregunta con tu solución. Pero incluye tú codigo como texto tanto en la pregunta original como en la solución en lugar de imágenes. Para que se formatee (salga como en mi post) solo tienes que seleccionarlo y pulsar Ctrl+K

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver, no se si sea una buena manera de escribir el codigo pero hice un metodo POST : <form action="mostrardetalle.php" method="POST">

            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['ID'], COD, KEY);  ?>">

            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnAccion2" type="submit" value="Agregar2" align="center" style="background-color:blueviolet">Mostrar más </button>


          </form>

Comment: Y en otro archivo PHP con descripción de producto puse esto : if (isset($_POST['btnAccion2'])) {


    switch ($_POST['btnAccion2']) {

        case 'Agregar2':
            if (is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY))) {
                $ID = openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY);
                echo $ID;  Disculpa como lo hice pero no supe como poner salgo de pagina

Comment: @LeonPerezFabian La forma que indicas es correcta pero me parece que es añadirle una complejidad innecesaria en este caso. Tu solución implica más líneas de código (Compara lo que yo he añadido con lo que tú tienes que añadir para cada producto) y el empleo de un encriptado que para esta situación no parece requerirse.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo, trataré de hacerlo como comentas, apenas estoy iniciando con esto de la programación web y es un poco tedioso.